# Resizing matrix using pointer attribute

Tags: module, fortran, fortran90

I have a Fortran program which uses a routine in a module to resize a matrix like:

```
module resizemod

contains

 subroutine ResizeMatrix(A,newSize,lindx)
  integer,dimension(:,:),intent(inout),pointer :: A
  integer,intent(in) :: newSize(2)
  integer,dimension(:,:),allocatable :: B
  integer,optional,intent(in) :: lindx(2)
  integer :: i,j

  allocate(B(lbound(A,1):ubound(A,1),lbound(A,2):ubound(A,2)))
  forall (i=lbound(A,1):ubound(A,1),j=lbound(A,2):ubound(A,2))
    B(i,j)=A(i,j)
  end forall
  if (associated(A)) deallocate(A)
  if (present(lindx)) then
    allocate(A(lindx(1):lindx(1)+newSize(1)-1,lindx(2):lindx(2)+newSize(2)-1))
  else
    allocate(A(newSize(1),newSize(2)))
  end if
  do i=lbound(B,1),ubound(B,1)
    do j=lbound(B,2), ubound(B,2)
      A(i,j)=B(i,j)
    end do
  end do
  deallocate(B)
 end subroutine ResizeMatrix
end module resizemod
```

The main program looks like:

```
program resize

 use :: resizemod

 implicit none
 integer,pointer :: mtest(:,:)

 allocate(mtest(0:1,3))
 mtest(0,:)=[1,2,3]
 mtest(1,:)=[1,4,5]
 call ResizeMatrix(mtest,[3,3],lindx=[0,1])
 mtest(2,:)=0
 print *,mtest(0,:)
 print *,mtest(1,:)
 print *,mtest(2,:)

end program resize
```

I use ifort 14.0 to compile the codes. The issue that I am facing is that sometimes I don't get the desired result:

```
       1           0           0
       1           0           5
       0           0  -677609912
```

Actually I couldn't reproduce the issue (which is present in my original program) using the minimal test codes. But the point that I noticed was that when I remove the compiler option `-fast`, this problem disappears.

Then my question would be

1. If the pieces of code that I use are completely legal?
2. If any other method for resizing the matrices would be recommended which is better than the one presented in here?
3. The relevance of the described issue and the compiler option "-fast".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've read the code right it's legal but incorrect.  In your example you've resized a `2x3` array into `3x3` but the routine `ResizeMatrix` doesn't do anything to set the values of the extra elements.  The strange values you see, such as `-677609912`, are the interpretation, as integers. of whatever bits were lying around in memory when the memory location corresponding to the unset array element was read (so that it's value could be written out).

The relevance of `-fast` is that it is common for compilers in debug or low-optimisation modes, to zero-out memory locations but not to bother when higher optimisation is switched on.  The program is legal in the sense that it contains no compiler-determinable syntax errors.  But it is incorrect in the sense that reading a variable whose value has not been initialised or assigned is not something you regularly ought to do; doing so makes your program, essentially, non-deterministic.

As for your question 2, it raises the possibility that you are not familiar with the intrinsic functions `reshape` or (F2003) `move_alloc`.  The latter is almost certainly what you want, the former may help too.

As an aside: these days I rarely use `pointer` on arrays, `allocatable` is much more useful and generally easier and safer too.  But you may have requirements of which I wot not.

Comment: Hmmm, I think I see you point but I didn't understand why the original elements mtest(0:1,1:3) are returned incorrect. In some further testing, I noticed that if I print the matrix inside the subroutine, then the returning array is correct! So do you basically mean that if I don't set the extra elements inside the routine, the data for the other elements will be corrupted as well?

Comment: I actually was using a similar routine for 1D arrays so far without problem. Now I probably change them to use move_alloc(). I will change the pointer attribute to allocatable as well.